# Keynote, Pages and Numbers all quit unexpectedly

Tags: macos, crash, pages, keynote, logs

Today Keynote, Pages and Numbers all quit unexpectedly right after being launched. I only have time to see the "Select a document / New document" window for a second before the apps crash, leaving me with a Problem Report.

Yesterday I was using Pages and Keynote and they worked fine. I can't think of anything I did since then that could have caused this problem.

I'm running macOS 11.2.3 on a MacBook Air M1 and have the latest versions of the apps.

Below are parts of the log of the Keynote crash:

```
Process:               Keynote [801]
Path:                  /Applications/Keynote.app/Contents/MacOS/Keynote
Identifier:            com.apple.iWork.Keynote
Version:               11.1 (7031.0.102)
Build Info:            Keynote-7031000102000000~2 (1A104)
App Item ID:           409183694
App External ID:       842170568
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Keynote [801]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-06-08 23:58:57.257 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.2.3 (20D91)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        A43F48F6-B303-2BA9-9E6F-D2DDB0D3D4D6


Time Awake Since Boot: 1200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        2  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreText.fontdescriptorMatching

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT at 0x00000001a51407bc (brk 1)
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [801]

Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a2646320 __exceptionPreprocess + 240
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001a2374c04 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a270d064 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a270d30c -[__NSCFBoolean compare:].cold.1 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a259ec10 -[__NSCFNumber objCType] + 0
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a259ea10 -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToNumber:] + 32
6   CoreText                            0x00000001a3c421f0 +[FontAssetDownloadManager filterIncompatibleAsset:] + 832
7   CoreText                            0x00000001a3c425cc +[FontAssetDownloadManager availableMobileAssetsWithOptions:error:] + 848
8   CoreText                            0x00000001a3c42b2c +[FontAssetDownloadManager availableMobileAssetsWithOptions:manager:error:] + 76
9   CoreText                            0x00000001a3c40a68 -[FontAssetDownloadManager mobileAssetsForUnmatched:] + 148
10  CoreText                            0x00000001a3c40790 -[FontAssetDownloadManager downloadFontAssets] + 84
11  CoreText                            0x00000001a3c44f94 __CTFontDescriptorMatchFontDescriptorsWithProgressHandler_block_invoke + 36
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a231f8bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a2321420 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a232877c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580
15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a23292cc _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001a23333fc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a24ca060 _pthread_wqthread + 276
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001a24c8d94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a2494ce8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a2495098 mach_msg + 76
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001a25c8e98 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001a25c736c __CFRunLoopRun + 1216
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001a25c6740 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001aa0eb5c4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001aa0eb3f4 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 688
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001aa0eb124 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a4da082c _DPSNextEvent + 868
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a4d9f1ac -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1312
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a4d91060 -[NSApplication run] + 600
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a4d62804 NSApplicationMain + 1064
12  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a24e9f34 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreText.fontdescriptorMatching
0   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a51407bc -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 372
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a51407b4 -[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 364
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a51404a0 -[NSApplication reportException:] + 588
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a51f12fc uncaughtErrorProc + 156
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001a26cd654 __handleUncaughtException + 676
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001a23776bc _objc_terminate() + 132
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a248d0e0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001a248d06c std::terminate() + 44
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2321434 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a232877c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a23292cc _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a23333fc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24ca060 _pthread_wqthread + 276
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:: Dispatch queue: TSAFontResourceRequest.Network
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a2494d3c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2321a08 _dispatch_sema4_timedwait + 68
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2322018 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 76
3   com.apple.iWork.TSApplication   0x0000000107f542c4 0x107a28000 + 5423812
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a231f8bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a2321420 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a232877c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a23292cc _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a23333fc _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24ca060 _pthread_wqthread + 276
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d94 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8d8c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a2494ce8 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001a2495098 mach_msg + 76
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001a25c8e98 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001a25c736c __CFRunLoopRun + 1216
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00000001a25c6740 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00000001a4f20864 _NSEventThread + 216
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24ce06c _pthread_start + 320
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001a24c8da0 thread_start + 8

Thread 2 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000000014f513000   x1: 0x000000016d32dc20   x2: 0x0000000000000003   x3: 0x000000014f513600
    x4: 0x0000000000000191   x5: 0x000000016d32db68   x6: 0x0000000000000004   x7: 0x0000000000000005
    x8: 0x00000002026fa000   x9: 0x86908faffae700e5  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x000000014f513791
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x00000000fca02400  x15: 0x0000000000000002
   x16: 0x0000000000000038  x17: 0x000000016d32df42  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00006000033a6fa0
   x20: 0x00000001f889b562  x21: 0x00006000034cb380  x22: 0x00000001f8896000  x23: 0x000000020c768000
   x24: 0x00006000033a6100  x25: 0x0000600003a84140  x26: 0x00000001f8896cb2  x27: 0x00000001f8898518
   x28: 0x00000001a29cc90c   fp: 0x000000016d32e620   lr: 0x171d8001a51407b4
    sp: 0x000000016d32e5d0   pc: 0x00000001a51407bc cpsr: 0x60001000
   far: 0x00000002026fad50  esr: 0xf2000001
```

**...**

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 30221
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=1.0G resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=1.0G(100%)
Writable regions: Total=1.6G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=1.6G(100%)
 
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Accelerate framework               256K        2 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CG backing stores                 3264K        6 
CG image                            64K        1 
CG raster data                    7936K      215 
CoreAnimation                       96K        6 
CoreGraphics                        16K        1 
CoreUI image data                 1040K        7 
Foundation                          48K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                           286.4M       53 
MALLOC guard page                  192K       10 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         952.0M        8         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
MALLOC_NANO (reserved)           384.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
SQLite page cache                   64K        1 
STACK GUARD                       56.2M       14 
Stack                             14.9M       14 
VM_ALLOCATE                       1296K       24 
__AUTH                            1403K      328 
__AUTH_CONST                      20.3M      543 
__CTF                               759        1 
__DATA                            23.0M      554 
__DATA_CONST                      23.1M      558 
__DATA_DIRTY                      2364K      263 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       492.9M       26 
__OBJC_CONST                      3859K      311 
__OBJC_RO                         64.5M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         2544K        1 
__TEXT                           551.4M      582 
__UNICODE                          588K        1 
mapped file                      374.5M      128 
shared memory                       80K        5 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              3.2G     3670 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.9G     3670 

Model: MacBookAir10,1, BootROM 6723.81.1, proc 8:4:4 processors, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_AppleM1Item, Apple M1, spdisplays_builtin
Memory Module: lp_ddr4
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme, wl0: Dec 31 2020 21:39:03 version 18.20.222.20.7.8.104 FWID 01-1b2645bc
Bluetooth: Version 8.0.3d9, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
```

Answer (score 2):

This crash signature suggests that you may have one or more corrupted fonts installed. Try restoring the standard system fonts.

1. Open `/Applications/Font Book`.
2. Choose `File > Restore Standard Fonts...`.
3. Press 'Proceed'.
4. Restart your Mac. (This is not strictly necessary in many cases, but it's possible that some resident framework could be holding on to a memory-mapped font, and restarting will eliminate that possibility.)

Comment: I got the following message: "**The standard font check is complete. No problems were encountered.** Your system already contains standard system fonts and no others. No changes were made." Howeve, the 3 apps now work. I can't know for sure this was what fixed the problem but I'll mark the answer as accepted if the crashes don't happen again.

Comment: Alright so the apps launch normally, but pages will crash depending on which template I use to create a new document (I've only found one template that crashed it). Also, Keynote crashes when I try to export the file as a PowerPoint file.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this worked for me, thanks.

Comment: @Eoin Could you try exporting a Keynote file as a PowerPoint file? This induces a crash for me.

Comment: @NawraC I don't use Keynote, but I've just checked and this works fine for me, so I guess we have a different issue.

Comment: @NawraC Can you boot into Recovery mode and run Disk First Aid on your boot volume? I want to make sure you don't have filesystem corruption.

Comment: @pion The crashes have disappeared now... If they occur again I'll make sure to do that, thanks.

Comment: @NawraC Glad to hear it! If you're satisfied with this answer, would you kindly mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your Mac os system version is not up to date : 11.2.3

Wonce updated to 11.4 you vill be cleared of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact issue today. I've found that if you keep trying the export, every nth time it works.

Around 4 or 5 tries is working for me.

```
Mac OS: 12.0 Beta (21A5506j)
MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
```